# Jquery variable from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that has an array variable. I would like to get this array from PHP side. But I could not do it.  Can anyone help me to how to get labels from the php side?
I looked other questions but most questions are regarding to passing jquery to php. my one is reverse side.

```
   $form_card.on('click', function(e) {
            if(!$form_card.hasClass('card-expanded')) {
                var template = Handlebars.compile($note_form_template),
                    context = {
                        'labels': [
                            {
                                'text': 'label 1',
                                'text_safe': 'label_1',
                                'type': 'default'
                            },
                            {
                                'text': 'label 2',
                                'text_safe': 'label_2',
                                'type': 'warning'
                            },
                            {
                                'text': 'label 3',
                                'text_safe': 'label_3',
                                'type': 'danger'
                            },
                            {
                                'text': 'label 4',
                                'val': 'label_4',
                                'type': 'success'
                            },
                            {
                                'text': 'label 5',
                                'text_safe': 'label_5',
                                'type': 'primary'
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                    html = template(context);

                $form.hide().html(html);
                $note_form_text.hide();
```

Here is my ajax function...

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: SITE_URL + 'nsys/dashboard/noteLabels',
    //dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
       var res = JSON.parse(result);
    },
});
return res;
```

}

and this is my php side ...

```
 public function noteLabels()
{
    $labels = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'label 1',
            'text_safe' => 'label_1',
            'type' => 'default'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'label 2',
            'text_safe' => 'label_2',
            'type' => 'warning'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'label 3',
            'text_safe' => 'label_3',
            'type' => 'danger'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'text' => 'label 4',
            'val' => 'label_4',
            'type' => 'success'
        ),
        4 => array(
            'text' => 'label 5',
            'text_safe' => 'label_5',
            'type' => 'primary'
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($labels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with it :

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: SITE_URL + 'nsys/dashboard/noteLabels',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
       var resource = JSON.parse(result);
       var res = resource.type // example if i want to get type
       //Then loop your data, because your data is array now. You can see with it: $('#result').append(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi. Thanks for you respons. I believe something like this will work. But this not worked.   context = {
                        'labels':$.ajax({ dataType: 'json', type: "GET", url: SITE_URL + 'nsys/dashboard/noteLabels', async: false}).responseText,
                    };

Comment: I only give an example brother, see my updated answer